# Skewed ListView in Android

Tags: android, listview, scrollview, parallax

I am seeking help here for develop a layout which is unknown to me. 
The thing is called skewed view. [There is an iOS library for the same](https://github.com/MP0w/MPSkewed). I am searching for the alternative library or any other solution in android.

I have already implemented parallax effects when scrolling in each item of list view, But the problem is I cant get this skewed/slopped look in my items. 
 I have searched a lot in internet, but so far no luck with it. It would be nice if there is any links or references as well.

[image]

Comment: Why -1? please tell me the reason also.

Comment: If you don't find then just knock me here, i will show you the rest. First try by yourself .

Comment: Judging by the bg parallax effect, the cells are not actually drawn skewed. Either that or the library first skews the bg and then skews the cell in the opposite way.

I would go the naive way of drawing rectangle cells with a small part of the next image's cell at the bottom.

Comment: @ZahidulIslam which flag do i need to set? is there any such type flag?

Comment: if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            Window w = getWindow();
            w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN);
            w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION);
            w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
        }

it will make the full height scrolling . But it's not for the parallax effect.

Comment: its not helped bro. I looking to achieve this -> https://github.com/MP0w/MPSkewed

Comment: I don't think android have any built in support for this feature. It's the violation of android UI design pattern.